# To retain dropdownlist (outside gridview) selected value after clicking "edit" in the gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist and a button outside of a gridview, which is used to control the data to be displayed in the gridview. Also, I have "edit" in my gridview. How can I retain the value of the dropdownlist and gridview data after I click on the "edit" in my gridview?

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Yes/asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="btnOnClick" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnRowEditing="gvUpdateMsg_Rowediting" OnRowUpdating="gvUpdateMsg_Rowupdating" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="gvUpdateMsg_Cancelingedit">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                        Text="Confirm"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                        Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                        Text="Reply"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                  ........
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            .......


     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "OnClick" event to your btnEdit button like the following:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
CommandName="Edit" Text="Reply" OnClick="btnEdit_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    LinkButton btnEdit = (LinkButton)clickedRow.FindControl("btnEdit");
    string any_data_for_gridview = clickedRow.Cells[1].Text; //change number 1
    string any_data_for_ddl = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```